# Scala Spark Structured Streaming Filter by TimestampType within Struct Field

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have multiple Data Types within a defined schema. Trying to find a good way to filter by TimestampType to transform all TimeStampType fields from long to datetime. I'm able to filer using .dtypes within the stream on StringType but run into issues when trying to filter with .dtypes of StructFields and StructTypes. **Is there a way to filter only TimestampType's within a Struct?** Below is the sudo code I'm using which is in Scala 2.11 using spark structured streaming

```
val isoDateFormatter = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"

val ExampleDataFrameLoad = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("subscribe", topics.keys.mkString(","))
    .options(kafkaConfig)
    .load()
    .select($"key".cast(StringType), $"value".cast(StringType), $"topic")
    // Convert untyped dataframe to dataset
    .as[(String, String, String)]
    // Merge all manifests for vehicle in minibatch
    .groupByKey(_._1)
    //Start of merge
    .flatMapGroupsWithState(OutputMode.Append, GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout)(mergeGroup)
    // .select($"key".cast(StringType),from_json($"value",schema).as("manifest"))
    .select($"_1".alias("key"), $"_2".alias("jsonvalues"))
    .select("key", "jsonvalues.*")

val ExampleDataFrame = ExampleDataFrameLoad
 ExampleDataFrame.dtypes.foreach(println)
/* Returns      
(key,StringType)
(contractVersion,StringType)
(metaData,StructType(StructField(Test,StringType,true), StructField(DateUtc,TimestampType,true) 
*/

*Uses the following objects
   import java.sql.Timestamp

 object ManifestClasses {
 
 final case class ProductManifestDocument(
                                        contractVersion: Option[String],
                                        metaData: DocumentMetaData 
                                      )
                                      
final case class DocumentMetaData(
                                 Test: Option[String]
                                 DateUtc: Timestamp
                               ) 
*/
 

 ExampleDataFrame
    //brings back data fields with types
    .dtypes
   //Currently returning empty but works for StringType 
    .filter(_._2 == "TimestampType")

    .map(_._1)
    //Tranforms all timestamp longs to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z' format
    .foldLeft(ExampleDataFrame)((df, colName) => df.withColumn(colName, date_format(col(colName), isoDateFormatter)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the structType as below -

> Changing the date format of timestamp type in place

### Load the test data

```scala
val ExampleDataFrame = spark.sql("select key, contractVersion, metaData from values " +
      "('k1', 'v1', named_struct('Test', 'test1', 'DateUtc', cast(unix_timestamp() as timestamp))) " +
      "T(key, contractVersion, metaData)")
    ExampleDataFrame.show(false)
    ExampleDataFrame.printSchema()
    ExampleDataFrame.dtypes.foreach(println)
    /**
      * +---+---------------+----------------------------+
      * |key|contractVersion|metaData                    |
      * +---+---------------+----------------------------+
      * |k1 |v1             |[test1, 2020-06-23 14:39:55]|
      * +---+---------------+----------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- key: string (nullable = false)
      * |-- contractVersion: string (nullable = false)
      * |-- metaData: struct (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- Test: string (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- DateUtc: timestamp (nullable = true)
      *
      * (key,StringType)
      * (contractVersion,StringType)
      * (metaData,StructType(StructField(Test,StringType,false), StructField(DateUtc,TimestampType,true)))
      */
```

### Convert timestamp from struct to specific date format

```scala
    val isoDateFormatter = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
    val processedDF = ExampleDataFrame.withColumn("metaData", struct($"metaData.Test",
      date_format($"metaData.DateUtc", isoDateFormatter)))
      processedDF.show(false)

    /**
      * +---+---------------+-----------------------------+
      * |key|contractVersion|metaData                     |
      * +---+---------------+-----------------------------+
      * |k1 |v1             |[test1, 2020-06-23T14:51:17Z]|
      * +---+---------------+-----------------------------+
      */
```

### Update-1 (based on comments)

### Extracting out the `timestamptype` from structType as a separete column

```scala
ExampleDataFrame.schema
      .filter(_.dataType.isInstanceOf[StructType])
      .flatMap(s => s.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
        .filter(_.dataType == TimestampType)
        .map(f => s"${s.name}.${f.name}")
      )
      .foldLeft(ExampleDataFrame)((df, colName) => df.withColumn(colName, date_format(col(colName), isoDateFormatter)))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+---------------+----------------------------+--------------------+
      * |key|contractVersion|metaData                    |metaData.DateUtc    |
      * +---+---------------+----------------------------+--------------------+
      * |k1 |v1             |[test1, 2020-06-23 21:40:36]|2020-06-23T21:40:36Z|
      * +---+---------------+----------------------------+--------------------+
      */
// use df.select("`metaData.DateUtc`") to select the columns having dot(.)
```

Comment: The select option is good, the only problem is I have about 100 columns to select which is why I used the manifest.* option. I also have the .withcolumn conversion working but the problem is that it drops the existing columns from the schema once the new field is added.  This works but drops the existing columns within the schema        
       .withColumn("metaData",
        struct(lit(date_format(col("metaData.DateUtc"), isoDateFormatter)) as "collectionDateUtc"
        )
      )

Comment: Is there a good way to change .dtypes to list the decomposs the StructField then the filter would pick up the Timestamp Type               
       (key,StringType)
      (contractVersion,StringType)                                       
      (DateUtc,TimestampType,true)